# What does m-mode and s-mode stand for in terms of operating system?

Tags: operating-system, riscv

What does it mean for the operating system to be in "S-Mode", and what does it mean for an operating system to be in "M-Mode", and what is the difference between the two?

I keep finding articles about kernel mode and user mode, but what is S-mode?

Answer (score 2):

In the operating system there are 3 modes: user mode (U), machine mode (M) and supervisor mode (S).

Machine mode: it is the most privileged mode because it has full access to the hardware (io, memory, interrupt)

User mode: this mode does not have access to some of the privileged instructions because any user can access this mode and that is not reliable.

Supervisor mode - This mode has an optional privilege mode, which makes it perfect for operating systems.

I hope this information helps you. I recommend that you read a book about operating systems.